# Chromecast keeps freezing during debugging

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging, chromecast, javascript-debugger

I am connecting to chromecast (1st generation model) on port 9222 and I click the shield icon to get debug scripts loaded. Debugger starts fine and I can add breakpoints and see console log. But when I start interacting with the debugger, or a break point is hit, or I start examining the objects in console, the chromecast starts freezing. The video playback becomes choppy, sometimes completely halts. Removing the breakpoints doesn't solve the playback issues, and I have completely disconnect and reconnect. Many a times, a video frame stays frozen on the TV and disconnecting doesnt make it go away, so I have to reboot the chromecast. Sometimes the debugger disconnects and I have to refresh debug window.
It happens so frequently that I can't get the debugger to stay connected longer than 5-15 seconds after starting debugging, which means I am disconnecting/reconnecting or rebooting chromecast for every few seconds of debugging.

I tried rebooting chromecast (many many times), restarting my browser, reinstalling my cast extension, trying different chromecast device and even trying different router. Is there any way or trick to get a solid non-interrupting debugging session going with chromecast device?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is a bug in the chrome remote debugger (a memory leak) that causes chromecast to freeze, crash or become unstable. It usually happens after a few minutes of connectivity so I am surprised that you mentioned it happens within 18 seconds; did you mean 18 seconds after the debugger is connected or after you hit the breakpoint? Regardless, the issue that I mentioned with the debugger is there and there is an internal ticket to address that; currently there is no work around. If in your case it is really as early as 18 seconds from the time you connect, then something else might be going on as well; can you please try that on a different app (if you have one) to see if it exhibits the same issue?

Comment: It is about 10-15 seconds after I hit a breakpoint or start interacting with javascript console. I will try on a different app.

Comment: Has this been resolved yet in 2022?